# My sql data base showing error when uploading sql file

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, upload

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `nand_ganga`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `sei92_assets`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `sei92_assets` (

 `id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'Primary Key',
 `parent_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Nested set parent.',
 `lft` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Nested set lft.',
 `rgt` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Nested set rgt.',
 `level` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT  'The cached level in the nested tree.',
 `name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'The unique name for the asset.\n',
 `title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'The descriptive title for the asset.',
 `rules` VARCHAR( 5120 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'JSON encoded access control.',
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `idx_asset_name` (  `name` ) ,
KEY  `idx_lft_rgt` (  `lft` ,  `rgt` ) ,
KEY  `idx_parent_id` (  `parent_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =46;
```

I get the error

> Documentation #1046 - No database selected

I cant recognise where/what the problem is.

Comment: "showing error" … **WHAT** error?

Comment: make sure you have selected `nand_ganga` database while adding or importing sql..

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
use nand_ganga;
```

before the table create statement to tell the DB which database to use, if none is selected.

Comment: its creat problem when uploading

Comment: You have to be way more specific than that. Please update your question with all the info necessary to know what exactly you are doing and was isn't working.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected

Comment: Then add the line `use nand_ganga` before the table create statement.

Comment: will this take some time when uploading??

Answer (score 1):

Before executing the table query run

USE `nand_ganga`

Answer (score 1):

If you import the database ( like via phpMyAdmin) select Database 1st, then go import.